# Entire project shown in import window

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I've been working with Unity3D since version 4.2 and just recently upgraded to different 5.X versions.

When importing an external package it used to show the import window with a list of all and only the package content.
After upgrading it seems to show how the package will fit into the project by showing the entire file structure and using white names for package elements and grey names for the rest of the files/folders.

I'm currently working on a very big project and this forces me to meticulously search through an unnecessarily HUGE list of elements looking for the ones I need to add or exclude from the import process.

Googling has been of no avail, does anyone happen to know how to hide my project files from that window?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> THIS ANSWER IS STILL VALID ON 23/03/17. THIS MAY CHANGE IN FUTURE
>   RELEASES

After googling everything and trying to force different combinations of settings my conclusion is that this is not possible.

I really hope Unity will decide to rollback this change, as it makes working with big projects really frustrating.